# CentOS 7 - Could not boot after kernel update to 5.x from 3.10 on nvme device

Tags: linux-kernel, centos7

I installed CentOS 7.6 on a system with NVME drive. Everything went successfuly and the system was behaving as expected. It came with kernel 3.10 by default so I upgraded the kernel to the latest (5.1.5) and changed kernel boot order in grub. However, whenever the system is rebooted with 5.x kernel version, it goes into emergency mode with the below error:

```
Could not boot
/dev/centos/root doesn't exist
/dev/centos/swap doesn't exist
/dev/mapper/centos-root doesn't exist
```

The system reboots just fine if I switch back to kernel version 3.10. I am getting this error only with 5.x version. 
I compared /boot/initramfs for both 3.x and 5.x and saw below kernel drivers included in 3.x, but not in 5.x

```
lsinitrd -k <5.x kernel version>

usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvdimm
usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvdimm/libnvdimm.ko.xz
usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvdimm/nd_btt.ko.xz
usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvdimm/nd_pmem.ko.xz
usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme
usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-57.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme/host
usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme/host/nvme-core.ko.xz
usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme/host/nvme.ko.xz
```

Therefore, I performed the below command to include nvme drivers in 5.x and rebuilt initramfs.

```
echo 'add_drivers+=" nvme "' > /etc/dracut.conf.d/nvme.conf
```

Once I did this, I could see nvme drivers being included in 5.x initramfs (different filenames though).

```
usr/lib/modules/5.1.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvdimm
usr/lib/modules/5.1.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvdimm/nd_btt.ko
usr/lib/modules/5.1.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvdimm/nd_pmem.ko
usr/lib/modules/5.1.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme
usr/lib/modules/5.1.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme/host
usr/lib/modules/5.1.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko
usr/lib/modules/5.1.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/nvme/host/nvme-tcp.ko
```

I rebooted the system again with 5.x kernel version and again I get the same error. I also read up about some rootdelay in case the device is delayed in being detected by the kernel, however, I didn't try that given the system starts just fine with kernel 3.x.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?